# Optimus and the comparative and superlative uses of adjectives in Latin

Tags: adjective, comparative, superlatives

What are the superlative and comparative forms of "optimus"?

Why is it also used as a simple adjective, meaning simply "excellent" and not a comparative?

Isn't "optimus" a suppletive comparative for "bonus"?

What are the differences in Latin in the use of the superlative, comparative and normal adjectives? I read that Latin was more flexible than English. What does it mean concretely?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bunch of questions, so I will give only a short answer to each.
If you want more details, please ask a follow-up question with a narrower focus to dig deeper.

> What are the superlative and comparative forms of "optimus"?

There are none, as *optimus* is a superlative already.
It is not unique in that respect; *pessimus*, *maximus*, and *minimus* behave similarly.
You could always form **optimior* and **optimissimus*, but as far as I know they have never been used.
And even if you can find an attestation (I couldn't in a classical text corpus), such forms are certainly not a part of standard Latin of any era.

> Why is it also used as a simple adjective, meaning simply "excellent" and not a comparative?

Latin superlatives are often used absolutely, without comparison.
Just like *optimus* can mean "best" or "very good", the regular *altissimus* can mean "tallest" or "very tall".
English doesn't do this to the same extent, so it is often most natural to translate a superlative using "very" or some other form of emphasis.
*Optimus* is not special in this respect.

> Isn't "optimus" a suppletive comparative for "bonus"?

It is the suppletive superlative of *bonus*.
The comparative would be *melior*.
All degrees of comparison look different.

> What are the differences in Latin in the use of the superlative, comparative and normal adjectives? I read that Latin was more flexible than English. What does it mean concretely?

Without more context, it's hard to tell what was meant; I can't give a more concrete answer without a more concrete question.
I suppose it meant that comparative and superlative forms in Latin do not always imply comparison.
This is rarer with the comparative than the superlative.

Comment: I could try to edit my question, but you already gave good and interesting answers. Thanks. For the 3rd question, I think I will make it a separated question later.

Comment: [_proximus_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpropior) is also an interesting example. It is also a superlative used as an adjective. The original adjective [_propis_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpropior) was obsolete in Classical times, but not the regularly-formed adverb _prope_

Comment: @Quidam I updated the third point, as I had made a small mistake: *optimus* is not the comparative but the superlative, but otherwise the answer stands. I'd be happy to see a follow-up question or several.